# CodeIgniter custom 404 message

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

I am trying to display an error message on CodeIgniter error page. I am trying this:

Controller/entries.php

```
public function show_entry()

{
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

if ($id !== FALSE)
{
    ..
}
else
{
log_message('error', 'The post ID is missing.');
}
```

Shouldnt this display my error message '`The post ID is missing`' on the CodeIgniter's default 404 error message ie. "`The page you requested was not found`."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The logging class is for writing messages to a log file (ideally somewhere that the user can't read it as it can have information on the inner-workings of your cite). It is something which is really beneficial to you above all.

To display a custom error message, you'll need to either use show_error or, probably more likely in this case, show_404 (both methods documented [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i couldnt find example use of show_404. I've tried using `show_404('Post ID is missing');` but it doesnt work.

Comment: yeah that works fine. was just wondering about show_404 after seeing your post, but thanks anyway.